# sharepoint in Light switch Datasource Error

Tags: c#, html, sharepoint, datasource, visual-studio-lightswitch

when i connect share point data source in my light switch HTML application have one exception
**listdata.svc**

does not appear to be a valid site SharePoint 2010 (or later) with an installation of WCF Data Services is required.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an authentication error to connect to the service.
the service actual path is :

```
http://[YourSharePointSite]/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/
```

make sure you able to access this path and you enabled external access to it

Comment: when i enter this url(http://[YourSharePointSite]/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/) in browser i got answer (like xml file)